# Rebuilding a script in an SSIS Script component fails with "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\users\........"

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

I have an error on a script component when I open an ssis project in VS 2019.  The error is "The binary code for the script is not found....".  So, I opened the component, opened the script and proceeded to save it, then rebuild it.  The rebuild errors with "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\users........".  I've tried recreating the script, but the same error occurs.  I thought it was environment specific, so, I changed to another computer.... same error.  I then though it was project specific so I switched to another project... same error.  Help!  I'm about to call Microsoft.

Comment: Bleeding edge?  Follow thread [here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/SSIS-script-task-do-not-build/1354064)

Comment: This fixed the issue.  Thanks vhoang.  I had to install the latest version of VSTA, here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58317

Comment: vhoang, if you post this as the answer, I'll give you credit.  Thanks

Comment: Glad that was the issue and resolvable for you through an update.   I've converted the suggestion/comment to answer form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acknowledged issue in VSTA [discussed here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/SSIS-script-task-do-not-build/1354064) in the VS Developer Community.

If same issue; update to the version [Publish 3/15/2021](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58317) or a more recent release to fix.
See the VS discussion above for full details.